# Networking Between Tasks in AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to setup a cluster with several different tasks that need to be able to communicate with each other. I have turned on Service Discovery for each task and I see all of the Route 53 DNS entries in my PrivateHosted Zone get updated as I spin up new tasks, but for whatever reason when I try to use the domain name of a service (wordpress.local) My other container cannot resolve it. They are all on the same availability zone and the same subnet. I'm not totally certain what else I need to do in order to get these tasks to be able to communicate with each other aside from setting up a target group in my load balancer which seems unnecessary as I have Service Discovery turned on...